# Redux probleb Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

if i write this its getting Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

```
var dispatch = useDispatch()
var phone = useSelector(store => store.phone)
 dispatch(phonePagePhone(window.location.href.split('/').splice(-1)))
```

but if i write thiss no errors:

```
 var phone = useSelector(store => store.phone)
```

why if i use useSelector and useDispatch in same file grtting  error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. redux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be dispatching in a callback, not in the body of your component.

Like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
   const phone = useSelector(...);

   const handleSomeUserInitiatedAction = () => {
      dispatch(...);
   };
}
```

If you want to dispatch on first render, you could do it in a useEffect like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
   const phone = useSelector(...);

   useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(....)
   },[]);
}
```